# PHP ¿Como envio un XML a un servicio SOAP?

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap

Tengo una duda, necesito enviar este formato de XML a un servicio SOAP para obtener una respuesta, pero no se como añadir esas cabeceras

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.sunat.gob.pe" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>20100066603MODDATOS</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>moddatos</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:sendSummary>
         <fileName>20100066603-RC-20110522-1.zip</fileName>
         <contentFile>cid:20100066603-RC-20110522-1.zip</contentFile>
      </ser:sendSummary>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Estuve buscando y vi la función [DomDocument del manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) para generar XML pero no lo puedo enviar. También intente con [SOAPClient](http://php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php) pero no me queda claro como añadir las cabeceras.

Comment: Hola, te aunque sea un ejemplo muy particular, te adjunto un mini desarrollo en PHP. Descripción de la estructura del WS: https://wswhomo.afip.gov.ar/WSCDC/service.asmx?op=ComprobanteConstatar WS(PHP): https://gist.github.com/Reflej0/e30bfd999bcde47e880327bd5c4d824d

Answer (score -1):

Si el XML que muestras en la "plantilla" que tendria la petición que estarias enviando podrias usar ese mismo simplemente remplzanando los valores de los parámetros y utilizando:

- NuSOAP: http://www.mauricioalpizar.com/ejemplo-de-como-consumir-un-web-service-utilizando-nusoap-y-php-parte-ii/
  o simplmente
- SoapClient: http://blog.osusnet.com/2008/08/06/consumiendo-webservices-soap-desde-php/comment-page-1/
- SoapClient: https://www.ecodeup.com/como-crear-un-cliente-y-consumir-un-servicio-web-soap-en-php/

Pero si tu quieres construir el XML entonces comienza por investigar como construir XML aqui tengo algo muy, muy básico sobre XML en C#:

- Lectura XML: https://aprendetesto.blogspot.com/2018/07/lectura-de-archivos-xml-xmldocument.html
- Escritura XML: https://aprendetesto.blogspot.com/2018/06/escritura-de-archivos-xml-xmldocument.html